# How to discover current route during Opa5 tests?

Tags: sapui5

Anyone knows how to get current route or hashed URI during Opa5 tests? To be used in an assert call.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself faster than I imagined:

```
Opa5.getHashChanger().getHash()
```